# Existence theorem for inverse functions by Taylor expansion

Tags: analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

If in a  neighborhood of $x_0$  we have 
$$f(y-y_0) = (x-x_0)+o(x-x_0),$$
where $f$ is a monotone continuous function.
How to show there must be a continuous function $g$ such that 
$$(x-x_0) = g(y-y_0)$$
in a neighborhood of $y_0$?

In fact, I want a general existence theorem for inverse functions by Taylor expansion, but I am not sure the above assert.

Comment: Not sure that this is a good idea. Having an invertible function doesn't mean that its Taylor approximations are invertible.

Comment: Let $f$ be a function.  
$f$ has an inverse iff $f$ is bijective, that means iff $f$ is surjective and injective. $f$ is injective iff $f$ is strongly monotone.  
$f$ has a Taylor expansion at $x_0$ iff $f$ is analytic at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

A function has an inverse in a neighborhood of a point $y_0$ iff this function is bijective in a neighborhood of $y_0$, that means iff this function is surjective and injective in a neighborhood of $y_0$.

A function is representable in a neighborhood of $y_0$ as a Taylor series, iff this function is differentiable in a neighborhood of $y_0$. If a function is differentiable in a neighborhood of $y_0$, this function is continuous in a neighborhood of $y_0$.

The general existence theorem for inverses by Taylor expansion that you are looking for is the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

The theorem states that a function $f\colon x\mapsto y=f(x)$, analytic at a point $x_0$, with $f'(x_0)\neq 0$, has an inverse in a neighborhood of $y_0=f(x_0)$ that is a convergent power series, means an analytic function, and gives a formula for the general term of that power series.